# Intellisense Text Editor VB.NET

Tags: intellisense, text-editor

I need to espose some code in my app to the end user so that they can make modifications. Is there a free text editor with intellisense support out there, which I can embed in my application. The code will be VB.NET

Answer (score 1):

[#develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) is a free [Open Source] IDE for C#, VB.NET and Boo projects on Microsoft's .NET platform.

Answer (score 1):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) would work as well (although I don't think it has intelli-sense), but HUGE RED FLAGS are flying up when you say:

> expose some code in my app to the end
>   user so that they can make
>   modifications.

In my experience the end user should either be logging tickets of things that don't work, or at most getting to play with configuration files.

Comment: @rie819 - double agree with the Red flags!

Comment: the end user of the app are developers, and the code which will be in the text editior is sort of dymanic.

Comment: Sounds like they just didn't want to define their requirements then.  If the end user can change the application, you can pretty much throw QA out of the window, and PLS make sure that you have some system in place to make sure you can prove that bugs introduced in the system come from them and not from yourself.